# How to make some days of the week in DatePicker unavailable

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar

I am getting the sequence numbers of the days of the week from a database and I want to make those days of the week available in the `DatePicker` and make the rest unavailable. But all days become unavailable, except for the last (in my case, this is the last day of the year). What am I doing wrong? I took the code from the link as a basis: [How to black out specific days of the week (datepicker) [VB]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213801/how-to-black-out-specific-days-of-the-week-datepicker-vb) (by the way, it works).

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{                
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    var minDate = DateTime.Now;
    var maxDate =new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
    string r;
    string st = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string sql3 = "select distinct id_week from timetable,masters where 
    timetable.id_mas=masters.cod and masters.fio = '" + st + "'";
    using (OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql3, conn))
    {
        OracleDataReader reader3 = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader3.Read())
        {
            r = reader3[0].ToString();

            for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate> d; d = d.AddDays(1))
            {
                if ((int)d.DayOfWeek != Convert.ToInt32(r))
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(d));
                }
            }
        }

        reader3.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: MonthlyCalendar.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(2020, 3, 31);

Answer (score 0):

To make this work it is necessary to change some logic.

```
 int dayOfWeek;
 IList<DayOfWeek> dow = new List<DayOfWeek>();

 using (OracleDataReader reader3 = command.ExecuteReader())
 {
     // Prepare days of week that should be available
     while (reader3.Read())
     {
         var r = reader3[0].ToString();     
         if (Int32.TryParse(r, out dayOfWeek))
         {
             dow.Add((DayOfWeek)dayOfWeek); 
         }
     }
 }
 
 // Now prepare the calender  
 for (var d = minDate; d <= maxDate; d = d.AddDays(1))
 { 
     // If day of week not included to the list then blackout it.                
     if (!dow.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))
     {
         dateTimePicker1.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(d));                            
     }
 }
```