# HTML Date time or Date picker to only allow a specific day of the week to be selected

Tags: html

All I can find is min, max and step, but what I'm trying to do is have the date or date-time local picker only be able to select for example Saturday and Sunday of any week.

Is there a way to do this?...

I know I can validate it, but I would like to restrict the selection in the first place...

Odd question I know.

Comment: Refer this article might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579777/how-do-create-a-datepicker-with-only-sundays-enabled

Comment: Thanks! But, I believe that's an ASP reference no?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such build-in function in the specs as there is min/max/step -- these are the only ones.

The variations are just way too much. You must use validation. An easier way to do this would be using a plugin as [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/). [More on input type date - here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).